# Convert Selected.System.String to System.String

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

In Powershell, I'm calling [io.path]::GetExtension(..) as so:

```
...| Select-Object {[io.path]::GetExtension($_)}
```

and I get the following output:

```
[io.path]::GetExtension($_)
---------------------------






.dll                       
.dll                       
.dll                       
.dll                       
.dll                       
.dll                       
.dll                       
.dll                       
.dll                       
.dll
```

(Note some inputs lack an extension, so their output are empty)

And piping that to "Get-Member" produces:

```
   TypeName: Selected.System.String

Name                        MemberType   Definition                                
----                        ----------   ----------                                
Equals                      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)            
GetHashCode                 Method       int GetHashCode()                         
GetType                     Method       type GetType()                            
ToString                    Method       string ToString()                         
[io.path]::GetExtension($_) NoteProperty System.String [io.path]::GetExtension($_)=
```

However I want *System.String*, and not a *Selected.System.String,* as I want to Group-Object, and I (apparently) cannot group Selected.System.String as it doesn't implement IComparable.

Calling ".ToString()" doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't convert it to a string.

How can I produce a string, or convert the output to a string?

Comment: Change `Select-Object {[io.path]::GetExtension($_)}` to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Extension`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart "Property "Extension" cannot be found." In this case, $_ is a string when being piped.

Comment: @JacobColvin That doesn't seem to do anything. No output whatsoever; can't even pipe the output to Get-Member

Comment: What are you actually piping in?

Comment: @JacobColvin That has the same behavior. And I'm piping in a collection of strings. The strings are pulled from a CSV (output from a procmon done on another machine).

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show the other code you have? Because this works perfectly for me: `'C:\x.ini','C:\y.ini' | % { [io.path]::GetExtension($_) }` It outputs both extensions as System.String

Comment: @JacobColvin Sorry, first time I used the % solution there was a typo when I implemented it (how I was feeding in the input)! That solution works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I was assuming `IO.FileInfo` input objects (not unreasonable, since you did not specify what you were piping). In this case you would replace your `Select-Object` with `ForEach-Object {[IO.Path]::GetExtension($_) }`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart He did include the members in the post

Comment: If you want a complete answer you should show complete code. Or even better provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print your outputs as strings, try this:

```
'C:\x.ini','C:\y.ini' | % { [io.path]::GetExtension($_) }
```

> .ini
>
> .ini
>
> TypeName: System.String

In this case % or Foreach-Object will run the command for every input, generating the output you need. Select-Object will actually create a selection object which contains the output. There are many ways to print the contents of this object, but using Foreach-Object is likely the simplest.

Comment: Someone down voted you. I'm not certain why, since this is the correct answer. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @NexTerren Technically it's still fine to downvote an accepted answer if the quality is bad, or it's a bad solution, etc... However in this case I'm not sure why especially since they didn't leave a comment. Oh well

Answer (score -1):

If you're dealing with strings, I'd suggest just using regex:

```
$Paths -replace '.*?(\.\w+$)', '$1'
```

This will return you a `[System.String[]]` object with extensions in the form of `.exe`